# RedBeanPHP FUSE Model in a Zend Framework 2 application?

Tags: zend-framework2, redbean

I'm trying to use the ORM RedBeanPHP (v3.3) in a ZF2 (v2.0.2) application and I'm having trouble with its automatic FUSE model. I can't make it link to my model classes. It's not picking them up automatically and using "regular" beans instead.

I'm using the [RjhRedbean](https://github.com/richardjh/RjhRedbean) module to load up RedBean in ZF2.

My model class is the following, placed in the folder `.\module\Check\src\Check\Model\Model`.

```
<?php
namespace Check\Model;

use \RedBean_SimpleModel;

class Model_Check extends RedBean_SimpleModel
{
   public $id;
   public $type;
   ...

   public function open()
   {
   }

   public function toArray()
   {
      return array($this->id, $this->type);
   }
```

I confirm it's picked up by the autoloader since `$c = new Model_Check();` works.

My controller code trying to load all the `Check` model objects from the DB is:

```
<?php
namespace Check\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use RjhRedbean;
use Check\Model\Model_Check;

class CheckController extends AbstractActionController
{
   public function listAction()
   {
      $rb = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RjhRedbean');

      $checks = $rb->findAll('Check');  // does not link to my Model object

      foreach ($checks as $check) {
         $ar = $check->toArray();         // does not exist in the objects returned
         ...
```

The objects returned are `RedBean_OODBBean`

What should I put as the bean name in the `findAll()` method? I tried:

```
$checks = $rb->findAll('Model_Check');
$checks = $rb->findAll('Check/Model/Check'); 
$checks = $rb->findAll('Check/Model/Model_Check');
```

Nothing seems to do the trick. When creating a bean, I get the same problems too...

Thanks.

Comment: I expect this is something I need to fix. If you are willing to help me get this working, please can you email me at richard@richardjh.org. Once we have a fix we can then post a meaningful solution here. In the meantime I will read up on the automatic FUSE model. Look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this isn't working is that FUSE cannot automatically find the Model for the bean as it would normally do due to problems introduced in using namespaces.

You can work around this problem by using a class map file and defining all Models that you are using in there. Making sure you models are in the global namespace.

More information and examples can be found on my blog: [How to use FUSE models in RjhRedbean](http://richardjh.org/blog/how-to-use-fuse-models-in-rjhredbean)

Comment: Thanks! It works... I come from a C# background, so global namespace is somewhat of an heresy for me, but it does work... Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dsjt: I am glad I could get it sorted for you. I am trying to get this module accepted under the http://modules.zendframework.com so I am keen to keep on top of reported issues. Gabor, who is author of Redbean, is not keen on namespaces which may explain the situation here but he does offer help if you wanted to put this into a namespace at : http://redbeanphp.com/extra/php_5_3_namespaces. Thanks for trying RjhRedbean.

Answer (score 0):

I modified RjhRedbean module as followed:
 
1.Created a class named ModelFormatter 
this class does nothing else but return the appropriate namespace related to your models.
the namespace can be set in your config.

2.In the RjhRedbeanServiceFactory class added
    RedBean_ModelHelper::setModelFormatter($serviceLocator->get('ModelFormatter'));